# Cloud9 Stuck on loading screen

Tags: javascript, session, cloud9

I was tinkering around with my preferences trying to get emmet working for jsx files and I ended up turning on plugin manager. Now my projects won’t load and I can’t turn the plugin manager off without being in a project. Here is a screenshot:
[C9 Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKgXy.png)

I have no idea how to fix this and from what I’ve googled the only thing I’ve seen that was close was this [thread](https://community.c9.io/t/stuck-on-loading-screen/1561) where the solution was that he had a browser plugin that disabled referrers. From what I’ve googled on the subject Chrome doesn’t allow referrer disabling so I’m not sure if this is the fix or not, nor do I know how to do it in Chrome. If anyone could help me out that would be great.

Also in the screenshot I've included the console. Some errors popped up as well as a notification of this:

> `[OT] Ace session not ready for: /weatherApp/src/containers/search_bar.js - will setSession when ready!`

which would be the open file in c9. Not really sure what this means either and I didn't see any solutions when I googled the issue. Any help on this issue would be appreciated as I don't have access to any of my projects in c9 which is what I mainly use for an editor.

Thanks,